# How to generate input select in laravel blade form and customize its options value?

Tags: forms, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm trying to create a laravel form that have an input select generating from array of strings coming from controller.

How can I set values of options manually?

In controller :

```
public function create()
{
    $eventTypes = EventType::all()->lists('title');
    return View::make('events.create')->with(compact('eventTypes'));
}
```

In view (blade) :

```
{{ Form::label('eventType', 'Type') }}
{{ Form::select('eventType', $eventTypes, null, array('class'=> 'form-control')) }}
```

And select created as :

```
<select class="form-control" id="eventType" name="eventType">
    <option value="0">Sport Competition</option>
    <option value="1">Movie</option>
    <option value="2">Concert</option>
</select>
```

I just want to set values manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value in the options is just the key of the array.  The second parameter to the `lists()` method will let you choose a field to use as the key:

```
// use the 'id' field values for the array keys
$eventTypes = EventType::lists('title', 'id');
```

If you want to do something more custom than that, you'll need to manually build your array with the key/value pairs you want.

### Edit

As mentioned by @lukasgeiter in the comments, there is no need to call `all()` first.

`EventType::all()->lists()` will first generate a Collection of all the EventType objects.  It will then call `lists()` on the Collection object, meaning it will loop through that Collection to build an array with your requested fields.

`EventType::lists()` will call `lists()` on the query builder object, which will just select the two requested fields and return those as the array.  It will not build any EventType objects (unless you select a field built by a Model [accessor](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators)).

Comment: No need to call `all()` first. `lists()` also works directly on the query builder.

Comment: @lukasgeiter Absolutely correct.  Silly oversight on my part.  I have updated the answer.

Comment: @Mehdi I have provided an update to the answer that you may be interested in (update based on lukasgeiter's comment).

Comment: Thanks @all, really useful guides for new laravel developer